# cakephp ajax render

Tags: ajax, cakephp, render

Good Morning!
I'm facing a problem with ajax on cakephp.
In my view, I have a link with the class "event" pointing to the action "add" of an artists controller and a empty div with the "preview" class.
When the controller does its job, it renders the default view "Add" instead of the one I set with $this->render('preview','ajax'). Can someone help me out with this ?
Here is my js code in the view :

```
$this->Js->get('.event');
$this->Js->event(
'click',
$this->Js->request(
array('controller'=>'artists','action'=>'add'),
array('async'=>true,'update'=>'.preview')
)
);
```

My controller :

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->render('preview');
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correct. 

Is your $this->request->data or $this->data (depending upon your cake version) loaded with the form data?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing just one word: `ajax`.

```
$this->render('preview', 'ajax');
```